# Sweep to the right transition css

Tags: css, input, form-submit

I have a submit button which i need to sweep its background from left to right:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Request" class="sweep">
```

I need something like [sweep to the right transition](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/sweep-to-the-right-transition/). All samples are for **button , a , li and Div** tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to animate the `background-size` property to simulate this effect

```css
    input {
      padding: .75em;
      border: 1px #ddd solid;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #eee, #eee);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 0 100%;
      transition: background-size 1s 0s;
    }
    
    input:hover {
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Sweep to the right" />
```